# Implementation of Fermionic SWAP in Q#?

Tags: q#

Is fermionic swap (as described in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.00023.pdf) implemented in the Q# chemistry library?

If not, would this be a good contribution to the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have a fermionic SWAP implementation in the Q# libraries at the moment, no, but that would be very reasonable [contribution to the standard library](https://learn.microsoft.com/quantum/contributing/); we'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Awesome! Would this go in the Canon, or another folder in the Standard library?